# Odd UV issues when importing model from speed tree

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, import

I have just modelled a tree stump in speedtree, and I am now importing it into Blender. In Blender, I have added a face to the top of the object, added a stump top texture to this, and then added a subdivision modifier and modelled accordingly to achieve what I desire. however, I am having some issues, such as some strange texture stretching around the stump top. I am also wondering how I can get the top of the stump to look more vibrant and just how to make the stump more realistic in general. any help would be appreciated :)

[image]

[image]

[image]